# fb.ui callback function with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, fb.ui

I'm working with FB.ui. I need to write call back function. when user shares image in my application this callback function should be triggered by ajax call. when its get shared on fb then I need to get the id of it which I'm passing already with $(this).attr('data-id').

```
    $('.sharepicture').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
    var obj = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: TAB_URL + '?app_data=p,' + $(this).attr('data-id'),
            picture: ABSOLUTE_URL + '/images/app.jpg',
            name: 'myapplication.',
            description: 'I\'ve just created a image from collection of pictures in my application . To see my image click on the link above'
        };

        FB.ui(obj);
});
```

can anyone pls tell me how to write this callback function. i tried something like this but its not working..

```
$('.sharepostcard').click(function() {
        //alert($(this).attr('data-id'));

          var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
        link: TAB_URL + '?app_data=p,' + $(this).attr('data-id'),
        picture: ABSOLUTE_URL + '/images/app.jpg',
        name: 'myapplication.',
        description: 'I\'ve just created a image from collection of pictures in my application . To see my image click on the link above'
    };

    FB.ui(obj);
          $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://www.facebook.com/fbml/ajax/dialog/feed",
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      alert(data);
                  }

            });

        });
```

I'm sorry if similar post exists already here. I did search for it but I could not find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

FB.ui() allows a callback function as second parameter:

```
FB.ui(obj, function(response) {
                if(typeof reponse == 'object' && typeof response['post_id'] != 'undefined') {
                    msg = 'Message send.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Failed to send message.';      
                }    
            }
        );
```

Comment: Can this code be used as `&& typeof response['to'] != '3')`?

Comment: typeof variable will retrieve a string identifying the type of data, e.g. "function", "object", "undefined", "string", etc.
So in each case typeof ... != '3' will be true because their is no type '3' .